# Join same table twice to find missing data

Tags: mysql

I have one table called capacity_daily_values, in which I store daily values between countries in both directions.

The schema of the table is like that:

```
id | direction | date_id | value
```

I need to have for one date two lines in the table for both directions. Like that:

```
1 | 1 | 2015-01-01 | 1.00
2 | 2 | 2015-01-01 | 1.00
```

Unfortunately some of the data is missing i have values only for one of both directions and i need to figure out which dates are corrupt.

I have tried to left join both tables and see, which results have NULL values, but with no success.

```
SELECT * FROM `capacity_daily_values` c1 
LEFT JOIN capacity_daily_values c2 
    on c1.date_id = c2.date_id and c1.direction = 1 and c2.direction = 2 
having value is null
```

I appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want to list just the incomplete dates, You may use this:

```
SELECT date_id, COUNT(*)
FROM capacity_daily_values
GROUP BY date_id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
```

See my fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37c60/1

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular Join, like the one you used, and then select all entries not contained in that joined table.

```
SELECT c1.* FROM `capacity_daily_values` c1 WHERE c1.id not in
(
  SELECT c2.id FROM `capacity_daily_values` c2 JOIN `capacity_daily_values` c3
    ON c2.direction != c3.direction AND c2.date_id = c3.date_id
)
```

I list each pair of entries twice in my sub-table, to get both entry IDs.

All IDs with a corrupt date should not show up in this sub-table.

Comment: At a second glance, the LEFT JOIN solution (by e4c5) clearly beats me in terms of performance. The GROUP BY solution (by Roman Hocke) too. I recommend one of those.